# Run .sql files in sequence on sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

We have multiple `.sql` files and is there any way we can run them in single job  ?

Sample files.

```
 @task1.sql ; 
 @task2.sql ; 
 @task3.sql ;
```

Is there any way can I put all 3 above files in single files and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... yes.

**task_main.sql:**

```
@task1.sql
@task2.sql
```

**task1.sql:**

```
select deptno, ename, job, sal
from emp
where deptno = 10;
```

**task2.sql:**

```
select * from dept;
```

---

Running `task_main` from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> @task_main

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        10 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
        10 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
        10 MILLER     CLERK           1300


    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```